# How to add "<br>" to newline characters on custom forms

Tags: 2013, custom-form, multiline-text-field

A multiline text field on my OOTB display form in my SP 2013 list will appear as:

`#1`

`#2`

`#3`

On a custom form (before I make any changes to it), it will appear as:

`#1 #2 #3` with the "\n" still being in place instead of being converted to "
" as it does on the OOTB form.

I tried adding `disable output-escaping = "yes"`, but this didn't seem to change anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, I used the follwoing XSL expression. It was working as expected.

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping=”yes”   select=”ddwrt:AutoNewLine(string(@History))” ddwrt:nbsp-preserve = “yes”/>
```

Here:

- History is my Multiline Text column in SharePoint list with Plain
  Text format
- ddwrt:AutoNewLine is to apply Line Breaks
- ddwrt:nbsp-preserve is to Disable Special Characters

[Apply Line Breaks & Disable Special Characters on Multiline Plain Text Column of SharePoint List Custom Display Form](http://sprider.org/2012/04/14/apply-line-breaks-disable-special-characters-on-multiline-plain-text-column-of-sharepoint-list-custom-display-form/)